# How to find function orthogonal to given increasing function

Tags: orthogonality

I'm new to orthogonality of functions. I need to find the set of functions orthogonal to a given monotonically increasing function, say $f(x)=x$, over a given positive interval, say $[a,b], 0 < a < b$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define "orthogonal"?

Comment: $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are orthogonal over $[a,b]$ if the integral of their product over the specified interval is zero.

Comment: Can you somehow apply the Gram-Schmidt process to some function other than $f$?

Comment: @kimchilover Can you explain what you mean? I'm afraid I'm a beginner in this and not sure what you mean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with a function $h(x)$ which is not a multiple of $f(x)$.  Consider finding a $g(x)$ of form $g(x)=f(x)+ch(x)$, where $c$ is a real number to be figured out later.  You want $g$ to be orthogonal to $f$, which translates into some condition on $c$...